# Move folders up the file path of .class file in java

Tags: java, file, filepath

I found the class path of my running class by:

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

For which I got below path as my result:

```
\Users\vanburen\main_dev\vob2\SD\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes
```

I have to read an XML file in location:

```
\Users\vanburen\main_dev\vob2\SD\rulesXML\rules.XML
```

Can someone help me how do I move three folders up? I've tried using

```
getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile()
```

but that seems to be redundant. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Be careful doing this, as that file is almost certainly _not_ going to be at the same relative path when you come to deploy your application to a web server (I'm assuming it's a webapp given the `WebContent\WEB-INF`).  Far better would be to put it somewhere under `WEB-INF` and access it using `ServletContext.getResource`, or make the location a parameter (servlet context init parameter or a system property) that you can configure appropriately for each environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't found a better way to traverse up the folders other than using        `getParentFile()`, I've added the file I want to read to my classpath and got its location by

`URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(RULES_XML_NAME);
            File fXmlFile = new File(url.getPath());`

And read the file by using,
`File fXmlFile = new File(url.getPath());`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have `getAbsoluteFile()`, but `getParentFile()` is by far the easiest and most accepted method of navigating up the folder tree.

Comment: But if I have to move say more than three folders up, I have to use getParentFile() as many times which I think is very redundant.

Comment: Programming tends to be very redundant at times. I assure you that is the cleanest method of doing it. Tree traversal in any form rarely jumps more than one node at a time.